# Cannot retrieve GPS coordinates from pictures taken from Google Photos library

Tags: android, gps, exif, google-photos

I am trying to read GPS coordinates in my app from pictures taken from online Google Photos library.
I launch the Intent with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
```

And I select a picture which is for sure not present in the internal memory of the device.

Then in the onActivityResult I use:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
File outputFile = getOutputMediaFile();
copyFiles(imageStream, outputFile);
imageStream.close();
```

To copy the full content from the source picture to the destination picture without passing from the Bitmap compression.

Then I have a function that using the ExifInterface getLatLong functions reads the GPS coordinates, but it returns 0,0 ad latitude and longitude

Everything works fine for pictures already stored on the device memory, but if I try to pick a picture which is on the Google Photo cloud, the picture is downloaded correctly, I can save it, but there is not any useful Exif information.

If I go on my Google Photos app and check the information of the same picure, GPS data is there.

Is there any other way to retreive that picture with full Exif data?

Comment: If you are using the built-in `ExifInterface`, please stop, as [it has a serious security flaw](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/08/dealing-exifinterface-security-flaw.html). Use a third-party implementation (I link to some options in that blog post). It's possible that this will improve your luck getting the EXIF headers, but I doubt it. You might try copying the file to your development machine and double-checking the EXIF headers there (e.g., via `exiftool`).

Comment: Thanks for info. Anyway if I download the file from the web interface of Google Photos (photos.google.com) on my machine, all the necessary EXIF headers are there, but if I get if from the Intent not. could you suggest me any third-party exif library?

Comment: [The AOSP has several copies](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html) of a better `ExifInterface`. For example, I use one in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater).

Comment: Thanks for the info. But i think the problem is before the stage of reading Exif, since the file downloaded by the EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI does not have the Exif header in it. Maybe am I saving the file in the wrong way?

Comment: That looks good. Part of the reason for suggesting using the other library was to be able to run a test where you read the EXIF headers without copying the file. If I had to guess, though, the issue is within Google Photos, with them stripping out EXIF information for some reason.